# Sum functoin formula with filtered row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file that I want to apply the sum-formula to the filtered rows as well. Currently the total value does not change when I filter the rows. Could you please tell me how to correct this?

AM8

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Ordersheet!$AL$" & $AO$5 & ":$AL$" & $AO$8);
    INDIRECT("Ordersheet!$AK$" & $AO$5 & ":$AK$" & $AO$8);
    "<>NO";INDIRECT("Ordersheet!$AI$" & $AO$5 & ":$AI$" & $AO$8);"<>STORNO")
```

AO8

```
=If(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*ROW($A:$A)))=7;8;
    SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*ROW($A:$A))))

AO5=10
```

Excel-File

[image]

Comment: Look into `=SUBTOTAL(109,range)` this will ignore all filtered rows in given range and sum the values. `=SUBTOTAL(9,range)` will include the filtered values.

Answer (score 0):

To find the sum of filtered rows, you should use `SUBTOTAL(109,...)` instead of `SUM`. In below pics, you can see the difference when all rows are selected in `Col` versus when a few are.

Formula used is `=SUBTOTAL(109, B2:B11)` instead of `=SUM(B2,B11)`

Without filtered rows:
[image]

With filtered rows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `SUMIFS()` function (from the number and order of arguments) you can't use `SUBTOTAL()` directly, but you can do so, indirectly, by using a helper column.

The approach below involves you writing the formula

```
=SUBTOTAL(102,AL10)
```

in cell `BA10` of your Ordersheet tab (assuming that column `BA` is currently empty), and then copying the formula down for all the rows in column `AL` that contain data.
You can then modify your current `SUMIFS()` formula to the following

```
=SUMMEWENNS(INDIREKT("Ordersheet!$AL$" & $AO$5 & ":$AL$" & $AO$8);INDIREKT("Ordersheet!$AK$" & $AO$5 & ":$AK$" & $AO$8);"<>NO";INDIREKT("Ordersheet!$AI$" & $AO$5 & ":$AI$" & $AO$8);"<>STORNO";INDIREKT("Ordersheet!$BA$" & $AO$5 & ":$BA$" & $AO$8);1 )
```

effectively adding a condition that cells in column `BA` contain 1 (which they will only do if they are visible).
(obviously you will need to change all the `BA` references to a different column if that column is currently populated with data)

Comment: Do you have a `SUBTOTAL()` function in column BA for that row ? If you do, then I can't understand the problem without being able to see it...